# Proving that a continuous function on a compact set gives a compact image

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Why is being continuity important when we prove that a compact set is mapped to a compact set? 
Is it because if the function isn’t continuous at an x belonging to my domain then my limit might be infinity and so my codomain doesn’t remain closed and bounded anymore?

Comment: If we don't assume that the function is continuous, then the image of a compact set is an arbitrary subset of the image space.  Unless all subsets of the image space are compact, we aren't going to be able to conclude that the image is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a continuous surjective map between topological spaces, with $X$ compact. Let's show that $Y$ is compact. Let $(V_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ be an open cover for $Y$. Then each $f^{-1}[V_\alpha]$ is open, **since $f$ is continuous**. Now $(f^{-1}[V_\alpha])_{\alpha \in A}$ is an open cover for $X$, since $f$ is surjective. Now $X$ is compact, and so there is a finite subcover $(f^{-1}[V_{\alpha_i}])_{i=1}^n$ for $X$, where $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n \in A$ are fixed indices. Then $(V_{\alpha_i})_{i=1}^n$ is the corresponding finite subcover for $Y$.

So to concretely answer your question: if $f$ is not continuous, one cannot bring back the open cover of the image of $f$ back to $X$, to use compactness of $X$.